# Write A Smart Query on Oracle to Find Invalid SPs

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

The condition

- The SP must be existing
- It was valid on 10g but not valid 11g
- We can run a procedure to testify if they give the following errors:

  - LOOP FAILING WITH ORA-00979: NOT A GROUP BY EXPRESSION (on 11 g)

problem on 11g, not problem on 10g

```
CREATE TABLE testing (AAA NUMBER, BBB NUMBER);

DECLARE
CURSOR curTesting(myGroupID IN NUMBER) IS
SELECT DECODE(myGroupID, AAA, 'PP', 'PP_GROUP') AS p_type,
      COUNT(DISTINCT BBB) AS num_of
FROM testing
GROUP BY DECODE(myGroupID, AAA, 'PP', 'PP_GROUP')
ORDER BY p_type DESC;

BEGIN
FOR row IN curTesting(0) LOOP
NULL;
END LOOP;
END;

insert into testing values(1,2);
insert into testing values(1,2);

DECLARE
CURSOR curTesting(myGroupID IN NUMBER) IS
SELECT DECODE(myGroupID, AAA, 'PP', 'PP_GROUP') AS p_type,
      COUNT(DISTINCT BBB) AS num_of
FROM testing
GROUP BY DECODE(myGroupID, AAA, 'PP', 'PP_GROUP')
ORDER BY p_type DESC;

BEGIN
FOR row IN curTesting(0) LOOP
NULL;
END LOOP;
END;

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-979: not a GROUP BY expression
ORA-6512: at line 3
ORA-6512: at line 10
```

- ORA-918 COLUMN AMBIGUOUSLY DEFINED OCCURS

problem on 11g, not problem on 10g

```
select ps_id, product_scores.ps_id ps_id1, productId 
  from product_scores join (select ps_id productId from products_shop ) on
       productId = ps_ps_id     
 where rownum < 10;
```

Solution:

```
select t1.ps_id, t1.ps_id ps_id1, productId
  from product_scores t1
       join (select ps_id productId from products_shop) 
         on productId = ps_ps_id
 where rownum < 10;
```

Please write a query to see the invalid sp's due to the upgrade from 10g to 11g

Comment: if you can't query the metadata yourself, consider purchasing Toad or similar IDE, you will probably need it soon.

Comment: Please edit your question and post examples of queries which cause an ORA-00979 error to occur with 11g which did not have the same problem under 10g.  Thanks.

Comment: Since you've posted the sample code from bug 9478304, with slightly modified names, do you mean you want to run something against your 10g code to see what bugs/changes will be encountered *if* you upgrade to 11g? There are a lot of bugs out there and a lot are version dependent; see note 18571.1 just for the ORA-00979 list. It may not be impossible, but it's close. The ORA-00918 is effectively  a bug in 10g (5368296) that you got away with, and it works properly in 11g. I hope you aren't trying to avoid trialling and testing your upgrade path properly.

Comment: Simply, I have already updated the test environment from 10 g to 11g. Now I am testing all the environment to see if everything is all right. Those examples are known issues when you update the platform from 10 g to 11 g. Since there are half thousand SP, I need to find a way to testify and find if there are any SPs under those conditions  above.